# Forwarding a single port from one network adapter to another?

Tags: network, windows, parallels-desktop, ipfw

I have a Parallels Desktop virtual machine with Host-Only networking. I want to set up Remote Desktop on Windows (port 3389) while not exposing any other part of Windows to the external network. Parallels adds a virtual network adapter that allows me to communicate with the Windows machine. On OSX I tried to add the following rule:

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd ,3389 tcp from any to 10.37.129.3 dst-port 3389
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is there anything wrong with my rule? Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: I thought that ,3389 means any ip? Anyways, I tried your command and it still didn't work.

Comment: I think I found a mistake. The first part is the destination (according to your link), so I think it should be sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 10.37.129.3,3389 tcp from any to any 3389 in

Answer (score 1):

According to what you're trying to achieve, your rule is in a wrong position.

[This Source](http://blog.xeiam.com/blog/2013/06/27/port-forwarding-80-to-8080-for-tomcat-using-ipfw-on-mac-osx/) will show you how to set up a rule.
However, you're navigation FROM:

> sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 10.37.129.3,3389 tcp from any to any 3389 in

Please don't hit me with a stick, I'm unable to forward this on my Mac to test.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I realized this after I posted the question (see my comment on the main post above). However, it still refuses to work. Perhaps it's a problem with RDP; I'll do more tests.